# Why does this double-ended selectionsort algorithm not work?

Tags: c#, sorting, selection-sort

I just wrote a simple algorithm to sort integer-values in an array. When I try to debug it, it sometimes works and sometimes it does not. I really don't know why. Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```cs
void swap(int[] array, int left, int right)
{
    int tmp = array[left];
    array[left] = array[right];
    array[right] = tmp;
}

void selectionsort(int[] givenArray)
{
    int maxindex = givenArray.Length - 1;
    for (int border = 0; border < givenArray.Length / 2; border++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < givenArray.Length - (border * 2); i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                if (givenArray[border + i] < givenArray[border])            
                    swap(givenArray, border + i, border);
                if (givenArray[border + i] > givenArray[maxindex - border]) 
                    swap(givenArray, border + i, maxindex - border);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I usually generate 10 random numbers between 1 and 9999 and print them out. Then I start the sorting and then I print them out again. Here is the output:

```
[Random] >> 2257 | 2866 | 8796 | 4497 | 4697 | 2393 | 1004 | 4799 | 483  | 8500 |
[Sorted] >> 483  | 2257 | 1004 | 2866 | 2393 | 4497 | 4697 | 4799 | 8500 | 8796 |

Sorting failed at 2/3
sorting failed at 4/5

Array has been sorted in less than 1 ms
```

Comment: Can you give sample input/output of when it does and doesn't work?

Comment: I generate 10 random numbers between 1 and 9999, print them out and then sort them and print them out again. I'm going to edit the post to add that. Thank you

Comment: This is a good time to be thinking about writing unit tests. Write simple examples (say only two elements, both already sorted and in opposite order) and ensure it passes tests with those. Then build up to a simple, *static* example that doesn't sort right, and show us that one. Rather than going "this sometimes works, sometimes doesn't". Help us to help you.

Comment: You are making it non obvious where your intended sorted range starts and ends. Traditionally you'd loop from 0 to end in the outer loop and from outer +1 to end on the inner loop instead of whatever it is you are trying here.

Answer (score 1):

I updated your example to print the array before every iteration (I also adjusted the inner loop to not pointlessly start at 0):

```
    public static void selectionsort(int[] givenArray)
    {
        int maxindex = givenArray.Length - 1;
        for (int border = 0; border < givenArray.Length / 2; border++)
        {
            PrintArray(givenArray);
            for (int i = 1; i < givenArray.Length - (border * 2); i++)
            {
                    if (givenArray[border + i] < givenArray[border])
                        swap(givenArray, border + i, border);
                    if (givenArray[border + i] > givenArray[maxindex - border])
                        swap(givenArray, border + i, maxindex - border);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintArray(int[] givenArray)
    {
        var first = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < givenArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(!first) Console.Write(" | ");
            Console.Write(givenArray[i]);
            first = false;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

And see this output:

```
2257 | 2866 | 8796 | 4497 | 4697 | 2393 | 1004 | 4799 | 483 | 8500
483 | 2866 | 8500 | 4497 | 4697 | 2393 | 2257 | 4799 | 1004 | 8796
483 | 2257 | 1004 | 4497 | 4697 | 2866 | 2393 | 4799 | 8500 | 8796
483 | 2257 | 1004 | 4497 | 4697 | 2866 | 2393 | 4799 | 8500 | 8796
483 | 2257 | 1004 | 2866 | 2393 | 4497 | 4697 | 4799 | 8500 | 8796
483 | 2257 | 1004 | 2866 | 2393 | 4497 | 4697 | 4799 | 8500 | 8796
```

We can see after the first iteration that the second lowest value has moved into the last-but-one position in the array.

During the next iteration, we're trying to place the items in position 1 and position 8 (0-based indexing). But *the items in those two positions are never directly compared with each other*.

One fix would be to compare `givenArray[border]` to `givenArray[maxindex - border]` *before* your inner loop and swap those two items if necessary.

```
    public static void selectionsort(int[] givenArray)
    {
        int maxindex = givenArray.Length - 1;
        for (int border = 0; border < givenArray.Length / 2; border++)
        {
            if(givenArray[border] > givenArray[maxindex - border])
                 swap(givenArray, border, maxindex - border);
            for (int i = 1; i < givenArray.Length - (border * 2); i++)
            {
                    if (givenArray[border + i] < givenArray[border])
                        swap(givenArray, border + i, border);
                    if (givenArray[border + i] > givenArray[maxindex - border])
                        swap(givenArray, border + i, maxindex - border);
            }
        }
    }
```